# Paso de argumentos por referencia y por valor en Dart

Tags: dart

Estoy comenzando con Dart y no me queda claro si los argumentos se pasan por referencia ó por valor. De acuerdo a la documentación todo en Dart es un objeto. La documentación también dice que las variables se pasan por valor pero si la variable es una instancia de una clase entonces se pasa por referencia. Encuentro un poco inconsistente este tipo de afirmaciones. Puede alguien aportar un poco de luz sobre el tema?

Comment: Dart actualmente no soporta paso por referencia.